# Datatables: How to get variable value from another function

Tags: javascript, datatables

I facing small issue. How to get variable value from another function in Datatables.

My Javascript code:

```
var id = "";
var type = "";

show = function(id, type){ //id=5, type=3
        id = id;
        type = type;
}

var pTable = $("#example").DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    sort: true,
    ajax: {
        url: "/url/"+id+"/"+type,
        dataType:"json"
    },
```

Console log result:

```
GET: /url///;
```

How to get value ?
Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue following code:

`pTable.ajax.url("/url/"+id+"/"+type).load();`

Answer (score 2):

Change show function like this:

```
show = function(_id, _type){ 
    id = _id;
    type = _type;}
```

Comment: Yep, not a good idea to have arguments of the same names as variables

Comment: @chris97ong +1 It's same.